# PgwSlider equivalent for Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, css, content, jhtml

Is there a module for Joomla 3 that does the same that this module does https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwSlider or any similar alternatives?

Comment: Yes, there are loads of sliders/galleries for Joomla. Please check the Joomla Extensions Directory

Comment: But I didn't manage to find anything similar to this one, with this sort of sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

[Smart Slider 2 - Thumbnail vertical](http://www.nextendweb.com/demo/smartslider2/widget/thumbnail-vertical)

[Frontpage Slideshow Movies template](http://demo.joomlaworks.net/frontpage-slideshow/movies-template)

[DJ-MediaTools](http://demo.dj-extensions.com/dj-mediatools/)

... to mention just a few atop of my head...

Comment: You're quite welcome :-)